# Find a non-Lipschitz Riemann integrable function to which its Fourier series converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, lipschitz-functions

I'm asked to find a Riemann integrable function $f$, that is not Lipschitz continuous but its Fourier series converges to $f$ uniformly.

I took a function $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$. 
It's not differentiable at $0$, and around zero it's derivative is not bounded. I tried to find Fourier coefficients:
$A_n=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{|x|}\cos nx\,dx$,
$B_n=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{|x|}\sin nx\,dx$ --> Equals zero, even func on symmetric interval.

My main problem is to find $A_n$. I tried to evaluate the integral but unsuccessfully.

Comment: $$\log(\sin x)$$ over $(0,\pi)$ has nice Fourier coefficients. Try that.

Comment: Sorry I don't know yet how to use MathJax properly, that's why it looks a little bit messy..

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Regarding the MathJax, it was fine for the most part- you just forgot to surround the math code with '$'

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: An unbounded function can never have a uniformly convergent Fourier series. Evgeny: Are you allowed to use any theorems about Fourier series convergence, and if so, which ones?

Comment: @LukasGeyer: good point, I just thought to some non-Lipschitz function having a nice Fourier expansion. However, the semicircle function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ over $[-1,1]$ does the trick. The Fourier coefficients depend on values of Bessel functions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Yes, any such function would do, I guess, also $\sqrt{|x|}$ as used in the question. In order to show uniform convergence of the series, you only have to estimate the decay of the coefficients. However, to show that the Fourier series actually converges to the function you need some kind of result about pointwise convergence of Fourier series, e.g., for Hölder continuous functions.

Comment: Yes I'm allowed to use such theorems, I thought to use this one: if f(x) is 2pi periodic and continious and it's fourier coefficients sum absolutely converge then the Fourier series converges uniformly to f.

Comment: I thought to find Fourier series representation in this way:       $\displaystyle \frac{A_{0}}{2}+\sum A_{n}\cos nx+\sum B_{n}\sin nx$

Comment: @LukasGeyer: I forgot to mention you in my previous comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an explicit form of the Fourier coefficients, a good upper estimate is enough. Using your example, integration by parts followed by substitution $u=nx$ gives
$$
\begin{align*}
A_n &= \frac2\pi \int_0^\pi \sqrt{x} \, \cos nx \, dx
 = \frac2\pi \left[ \sqrt{x} \frac{\sin nx}n \right]_0^\pi - \frac2\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \frac{\sin nx}{n} \, dx \\
 &= -\frac{1}{\pi n} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx
  = -\frac{1}{\pi n} \int_0^{\pi n}\frac{\sin u}{\sqrt{u/n}} \, \frac{du}{n}
  = -\frac{1}{\pi n^{3/2}} \int_0^{\pi n} \frac{\sin u}{\sqrt{u}} \, du
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}{\sqrt{u}} \, du$ converges, there exists a constant $C$ such that
$\left|\int_0^{\pi n} \frac{\sin u}{\sqrt{u}} \, du\right| \le C$ for all $n$, and so $|A_n| \le \frac{C}{\pi n^{3/2}}$, and thus $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |A_n| < \infty$, implying absolute and uniform convergence of the Fourier series.

Comment: Oh didnt think about that substitution :) Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a common trick in Fourier series, similar in spirit to the way Riemann-Lebesgue is proved.